# If the stopping time is finite on the origin, it is finite for any other point, why?

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk, stopping-times

In the context of a simple random walk, a claim that I find on some proofs:

When proving that a stopping time at any point $x$ is finite, it suffices to prove that the stopping time at the origin is finite.

How so ?
Is this a consequence of the independence of the sequence of stopping times and the fact that they follow the same probability law ?

Comment: What do you mean by the origin?

Comment: "Almost surely" finite, i.e. probability $1$.  It follows from the probability when starting from $0$ of visiting $x$ before returning to $0$ being a positive value, and thus the number of returns to $0$ and then first hitting $x$ being a geometric random variable whose probability of being finite is $1$.